# How can I prevent PHP HTML type="hidden" from breaking?

Tags: php, html

Type = "hidden" in html is changed from f12 and break. how can i prevent this . I showed the place below.  i don't know php, please help. I searched but couldn't find anything. I did a few tries but didn't work . Do my query with if?

type="hidden" f12 "devtools" everyone can edit type="email" or similar and change the input value. then you can fill in something else and send

```
<?php 
    // Include configuration file 
    require_once 'config.php'; 
     
    // Include User library file 
    require_once 'User.class.php'; 
    
    if (isset($_POST['part'])) {
        $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();
        exit(createCommentRow($data));
    }
     
    if(isset($_GET['code'])){ 
        $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']); 
        $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken(); 
        header('Location: ' . filter_var(GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); 
    } 
     
    if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){ 
        $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']); 
    } 
     
    if($gClient->getAccessToken()){ 
        // Get user profile data from google 
        $gpUserProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get(); 
         
        // Initialize User class 
        $user = new User(); 
         
        // Getting user profile info 
        $gpUserData = array(); 
        $gpUserData['oauth_uid']  = !empty($gpUserProfile['id'])?$gpUserProfile['id']:''; 
        $gpUserData['first_name'] = !empty($gpUserProfile['given_name'])?$gpUserProfile['given_name']:''; 
        $gpUserData['last_name']  = !empty($gpUserProfile['family_name'])?$gpUserProfile['family_name']:''; 
        $gpUserData['email']       = !empty($gpUserProfile['email'])?$gpUserProfile['email']:''; 
        $gpUserData['gender']       = !empty($gpUserProfile['gender'])?$gpUserProfile['gender']:''; 
        $gpUserData['locale']       = !empty($gpUserProfile['locale'])?$gpUserProfile['locale']:''; 
        $gpUserData['picture']       = !empty($gpUserProfile['picture'])?$gpUserProfile['picture']:'';
         
        // Insert or update user data to the database 
        $gpUserData['oauth_provider'] = 'google'; 
        $userData = $user->checkUser($gpUserData); 
         
        // Storing user data in the session 
        $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData; 
         
        // Render user profile data 
        if (!empty($userData)) {
            $output = '<div class="user-card">'; 
            $output .= '<img class="userimg" src="'.$userData['picture'].'">'; 
            $output .= '<div class="userinfo">'; 
            $output .= '<div class="username">'.$userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name'].'</div>'; 
            $output .= '<div style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><a class="usera">'.$userData['email'].'</a></div>'; 
            $output .= '<a class="logout usera" href="logout.php">Logout</a>'; 
            $output .= '</div></div>'; 
        }else{ 
            $output = '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        // Get login url 
        $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl(); 
         
        // Render google login button 
        $output = '
            <a href="'.filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL).'">
                <div id="googleButton">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="text">Log In With Google</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        '; 
    } 
?>
    
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/gwuser.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
    
<div class="container">
    <form action="gwenter.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php
                if (!empty($userData)) {
                    echo( '<input type="hidden"  id="email" name="email" value="'.$userData['email'].'">');
                } else {} 
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php 
                // Kullanıcı giriş buton
                if (!empty($userData)) {
                    echo( '<button class="btn btn-success" id="part" type="submit">Join</button>');
                } else { 
                    echo( '<a class="btn btn-success alertsignin">Join</a>');
                } 
            ?>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
    
<div class="container">
    <!-- Display login button / Google profile information -->
    <?php echo $output; ?>
</div>
    
<!-- partial -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js'></script><script src="./js/alertjs.js"></script>
```

Here in this place, input place type="hidden" please help me

```
<?php
    if (!empty($userData)) {
        echo( '<input type="hidden"  id="email" name="email" value="'.$userData['email'].'">');
    } else {} 
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "breaking"? Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of the problem you have.

Comment: What does 'changed from f12' mean? Is that some function key in your editor?

Comment: Please do NOT abuse text attributes. There's nothing spectacular in your question that requires boldface text

Comment: I think you mean that by using the developer tools in your browser you can modify the HTML to remove the `type="hidden"` from the input. This is simply the case, and you shouldn't try to prevent it, if that is possible at all. The more pertinent question is: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: KIKO Software. because the user can send another mail instead of the email.

Comment: The solution is to not put the email address in the HTML in the first place.

Comment: Anything you send to a browser can be manipulated, **Anything**. You shouldn't trust anything you receive from a browser for that reason. If you don't want a user to edit the email address, don't send it. Find a way to match the completed form with existing user data on the server.

Comment: KIKO Software. sir, Is there any sample? how can I do it I do not know much

Comment: As CatchAsCatchCan said: Do it in PHP on the server. You get the email address from PHP, why can't you do that when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

## Do not do that.

**TL;DR** if you don't know enough to do it *safely*, do not do it *at all* until you have gotten more experienced - or believe me, you will regret it. *I* waited until I thought I was experienced enough. Ha! **I was mistaken**, and I regretted it. Do better than me.

---

*Always* assume that everything you send to the user is utterly, completely at the user's mercy. The best you can do is *try* to detect tampering.

In this case:

```
echo( '<input type="hidden"  id="email" name="email" value="'.$userData['email'].'">');
```

you could for example store `$userData['email']` in a user session variable (see `$_SESSION`).

For example:

```
// At the beginning of all involved scripts
session_start();

...

// This comes off!
/* echo( '<input type="hidden"  id="email" name="email" value="'.$userData['email'].'">'); */
// Replaced by:
$_SESSION['email'] = $userData['email'];
```

Then in the other script, the one receiving the form, you can even **fake** having received the 'email' variable from the form, while in reality you no longer do:

```
session_start();
$_POST['email'] = $_SESSION['email'];
// But use filter_var all the same!
// See: https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp
```

Now the receiving script can be sure that the $_POST['email'] variable was not tampered with, because it wasn't even sent in the first place.

---

Otherwise, you can store the variable into a protected string:

```
 $secret = 'SeekritPasswrd';
 $hash   = md5($secret.$userData['email']);

 $protected = $hash.$userData['email'];

 echo( '<input type="hidden"  id="email" name="email" value="'.$protected.'">');
```

When you read the data back, verify that `$protected` is correct:

```
 $protected = $_POST['email'];
 $hash  = substr($protected, 0, 32);
 $email = substr($protected, 32);

 $secret = 'SeekritPasswrd';
 $expect = md5($secret.$email);

 if ($hash !== $expect) {
     die("Data has been tampered with!");
 }
```

(You think this is clever? Well, why, I did too. Lesson learned: in some scenarios, *the above is not enough*).

If you need to send the client *elsewhere* with some information, **just don't**:

```
 CLIENT ---> YOUR SERVER      form request

 YOUR SERVER ---> CLIENT      form, in which you reveal critical information

 CLIENT ---> SOMEWHERE ELSE   # DANGER, WILL ROBINSON!
```

Instead, use a man-in-the-middle proxying or other means to secure the information:

```
 CLIENT ---> YOUR SERVER      form request

 YOUR SERVER ---> CLIENT      incomplete form, in which you DO NOT reveal information

 CLIENT ---> YOUR SERVER      incomplete form with client info

 YOUR SERVER --> SOMEWHERE    complete form with information the client can't see
```

The above you can do in PHP using the cURL extension, or other libraries that provide the same functionality. Note: not all ISPs allow this kind of connection (from the server to another server).

```
 SOMEWHERE --> YOUR SERVER    reply

 YOUR SERVER --> CLIENT       reply, with critical data removed if needed
```

It *is* longer and more complicated, no doubts about that, but it is *more secure*.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do I never resend information of an item that exists in database, I simply send the item ID  and query that items details from  the server side. If you want to insert user details dont resend in the form. For instance a customer wants to pay for a product which already exists in a database. Pass the product id only.

```
<form>
     <?php echo $product_price?>
     <input type='hidden' name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id?>">
 <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

To process this form, they user should have been logged in, get the user details from session.

```
<?php  
      if(isset($_POST)){
         //get product details from database 
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
         $product = "select * from products where id='$product_id";
        //from session get user info
        $email = $user->email;
          $data = array(
                       'product_id'=>$product_id,
                       'emai'=>$email,
                       'product_price'=>$product['price']
           );
            //insert the data to database 
       }
?>
```

With the above data users won't be able to manipulate some data. Here the only data passed through form was product I'd.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)